# Has anyone proposed a Pipe operator for javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Many languages have an operator that allows you to pipe the results of one operation into a call to another (e.g. the `|` operator in bash, the `|>` operator in F#).

One of the great advantages to my mind of the common idiom of method chaining in javascript is that it reads top-to-bottom, left-to-right:

```
var fooOddSquares = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    .filter(x => x % 2)
    .map(x => "foo" + x * x)
    .reduce(((acc, str, i) => acc[i + 1] = str; return acc), {});

// => {1: "foo1", 2: "foo9", 3: "foo25"}
```

compared to compositional code:

```
var something = func5(
    func4(
        func3(
            func2(
                func1(
                    somedata
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which reads right-to-left, bottom-to-top. I realize this could be cleaned up via function composition, but that's not necessarily the point. Just to be absolutely clear with what I'm looking for:

```
var something = func1(somedata)
    |> func2
    |> func3
    |> func4
    //etc...
```

Doing a google search on the pipe operator in javascript mostly turns up info about the bitwise OR operation. With some digging however I was able to dig up [this](http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html) article describing a dirty-hacked version of operator overloading that could implement something of what I'm talking about. I also unearthed [this](https://gist.github.com/impinball/31f0e25310396736185c) gist that describes said operator and says that "it has been proposed for javascript".

Looking at ES 2016, I see proposals for an exponentiation operator and the bind operator. Both are useful, but not what I want. So per the headline in the gist, has anyone actually proposed this for javascript?

Comment: Do you mean [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)?

Comment: JS is functional, but doesn't allow you to add custom operators. It's trivial to do with a custom function though, [and has been done](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs/#pipe).

Comment: Yes...ish. You can certainly do that with Promises, but I mean an infix operator.

Comment: Maybe you should just ask impinball about his gist?

Comment: @Bergi as in the Axel Raushmeyer article I linked to you can sorta kinda overload some operators by overriding the `.valueOf` method with a custom function (dirty hack, but interesting). And I've been a Ramda fan ever since I saw the Brian Lonsdorf vid. But I was curious when I saw that bit in the gist if anyone has actually proposed an infix operator like this. And yes I will :).

Comment: [Here](http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/cf4b61ea797c/javascript-macro-implementing-f-style-forward-pipe-operator.html) the `|>` operator seems to be implemented using a sweet.js macro

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you find that? I maybe used the wrong search strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This github repo](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind) and [my favorite issue within it](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind/issues/26) ;) discuss just that.

The proposal has been moving around in a small neighborhood of ideas for some months, but centers around using `->` and `::` as sugar around `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.bind`, very roughly.

The current draft is for `::` to sit between a scope and function (`instance::method`) and act much like `instance.method.bind(instance)`, locking the `this` scope of the function for any calls. Alongside that, `->` may be defined to pass a scope and array of arguments (as `apply`), so `instance->method(foo, bar)` would desugar to `instance.method.apply(instance, [foo, bar])`. At least, that's one of the directions that is being discussed (disclosure: that's my take on it).

Answer (score 15):

A pipeline operator has been proposed for ES7 (ES2016) in December 2015.

https://github.com/mindeavor/es-pipeline-operator

Comment: @DuncanLuk It recently advanced to Stage 1, should progress to Stage 2 relatively quickly.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned already a pipeline operator has been proposed for ES7 (2016), however that doesn't help much if you want to use something like this right now with babel which exactly how I came across this question 9 months later.

The biggest hitch in supporting the [es-pipeline-operator](https://github.com/mindeavor/es-pipeline-operator) proposal through babel as far as I know is the current inability to use `|>` or `<|` as operators which create syntax errors and cannot be fixed without changes to babel and unfortunately does not look like the problem will be resolved any time soon.

I would personally like to see the pipe backward operator added to the proposal as well since both forward and backward are useful in different situations.

For example, I use the pipe backward operator when modifying functions or anywhere I would typically use "compose" over "pipe" which I prefer in certain situations for readability.

```
const something = curry <| function(state, pattern) {
  // something
}

const something = function(state, pattern) {
  // something
} |> curry
```

Because these pipe operators are incredibly useful in functional style javascript programming and for the benefit of anyone who came looking for a solution to use this right now like me, I have made a babel plugin that uses the bitwise operators `<<` and `>>` which I rarely use to achieve both forward and backward piping for the time being and in the rare cases where the bitwise operators are required the use of the `"no pipe";` directive will disable the plugin for a certain scope.

https://github.com/michaelmitchell/babel-plugin-pipe-composition

Answer (score 0):

I usually just go like this:

```
var something = [somedata].map(func1).map(func2).map(func3).map(func4)[0];
```

It solves one of the main points in the question

> One of the great advantages to my mind of the common idiom of method chaining in javascript is that it reads top-to-bottom, left-to-right:` by taking advantage of how this already exists for arrays.

because this feature already exists for arrays, and converting something into an array, and back again is easy enough.

---

the above uses the names in the question, but here is a concrete example:

```js
console.log([9.3].map(Math.floor).map(Math.sqrt)[0]);
// or even this:
[9.3].map(Math.floor).map(Math.sqrt).forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: I mean.. this could be "The common idiom", without any new syntax.