# What does the "|>" operator do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was reading about JavaScript recently and ran into some syntax which seemed foreign to me:

```
const max = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
  |> Object.values 
  |> (_ => Math.max(..._))
```

What exactly does `|>` mean in such a scenario?

Comment: It's the [pipeline operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator), an experimental feature that allows for more readable function chaining.

Comment: maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54568053/1447675

Comment: @NinaScholz Rather of [Has anyone proposed a Pipe operator for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33550393/1048572)

Comment: I don't really think it's a dupe of any of those, but it should be folded into https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/476.

Comment: @deceze Agreed, it's not a duplicate (or else I would already have closed it), I just wanted to suggest that https://stackoverflow.com/q/33550393 has better answers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **pipeline operator** (`|>`) calls its second operand (which should be a function) and passes its first operand as an argument to it.

That is,

```
arg |> func
```

is equivalent to

```
func(arg)
```

Its goal is to make function chaining more readable.

---

As it is now (in 2021), it's a non-standard and experimental thing created by Mozilla that works only in Firefox by enabling it explicitly.

However, because of the usefulness of this feature, there are [two competing proposals in TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator), that would each add a different flavor of this operator to the language.

The exact syntax and semantics is to be determined, but in the simplest cases they will be similar to what's described here.

---

In Mozilla's variant (and the similar F#-style proposal) the code translated to this case will look like this:

```js
const max = (_ => Math.max(..._))(
  Object.values({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
)

console.log(max) //3
```

- First, pass `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` to `Object.values`
- Then, pass the result to the anonymous function `(_ => Math.max(..._))`
- Finally, assign the output to variable `max`

Answer (score 3):

`|>` is the [Pipeline Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator). It's currently an experimental operator - it's not yet or may never become standard for JavaScript. It's currently [only supported in FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator#Browser_compatibility) via enabling it explicitly.

As such, it is highly recommended to not use it, except for just messing around with it, given its lack of adoption and its experimental nature.

Answer (score -2):

Check this out!  You don't need any new syntax:

```js
const max = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}]
  .map(Object.values)
  .map(_ => Math.max(..._))[0];
console.log(max);
```

but also, if you already know what map is, the above might help you understand what `|>` is