# Passing function return to another function without directly declare any var or function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am studying javascript and i was wondering if there is any way of passing a function return to another function. for instance, let's say i have this function  `title.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")`  and i want to immediately pick it's return and pass to another function, like  `(test) => console.log(test)` .

What the second function will eventually do is to check if there is any - at the beginning of the string, and remove it case positive, i know there are other ways of doing this, but i want to know if is there a way with any function immediately after the return of the first function.

something like

```
title.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}{(word) => {
                                            console.log(word);
                                            //checkIfContains-
                                            //remove-
                                            return newWord}};
```

Comment: `secondFunction(firstFunction())`

Comment: Although maybe you mean [the pipeline operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55143363) `firstFunction() |> secondFunction`

Answer (score 0):

Coding is like basic mathematics. If you want to use the result of function A in your function B, you should go for B(A). Like I said basic maths, the function starts with A "inner function" and ends with B "outter function"

I couldn't really understand what you meant exactly with your example.

> let's say i have this function title.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")  and i want to immediately pick it's return and pass to another function, like (test) => console.log(test) .

You can simply do it like I told you above:

```
console.log(title.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-"));
```

In this case, `console.log()` is your B function and `title.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")` is your A function.

Comment: I understood your point, but what if instead of a console.log, i want to do a whole function  like the one in the exemple?
 {(word) => {                                            
                                            //checkIfContains-
                                            //remove-
                                            return newWord}};

in that case, is there any way of passing 
 {(title.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")) => {                                            
             //checkIfContains-
             //remove-
             return newWord}};

?